# Pytorch: How to make a custom Dataloader for CNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

I'm trying to create my own Dataloader from a custom dataset for a CNN. The original Dataloader was created by writing:

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_data, batch_size=64)
```

If I check the shape of the above, I get

```
i1, l1 = next(iter(train_loader))
print(i1.shape)   # torch.Size([64, 1, 28, 28]) 
print(l1.shape)   # torch.Size([64])
```

When I feed this train_loader into my CNN, it works beautifully. However, I have a custom dataset. I have done the following:

```
mnist_data = datasets.MNIST('data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

trainset = mnist_data
testset = mnist_data

x_train = np.array(trainset.data)
y_train = np.array(trainset.targets)

# modify x_train/y_train
```

Now, how would I be able to take x_train, y_train and make it into a Dataloader similar to the first one? I have done the following:

```
train_data = []
for i in range(len(x_train)):
   train_data.append([x_train[i], y_train[i]])

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=64)

for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
    images = images.unsqueeze(1)
```

However, I'm still missing the channel column (which should be 1). How would I fix this?

Comment: what is the format of your annotations/labels? Is it a single class classification task where are your in respective folder? for example if it is mnist you have all images with number "1" in folder names as "1" ?

Comment: No, I don't. It's just the same as the mnist dataset, I just removed a bunch of the ones from x_train and y_train, that's it. So shrunk the size of the input.

Comment: I think it is not a standard approach to use another off-the-shelf dataset functions ( `datasets.MNIST("data" ...` ) for your own dataset. if you describe how is your data (in folder/on kind of numpy array or any other ways) probably we can propose a kind of standard approach for you to train on your data. if it is opensource point out to the its repo, if not describe how it is.

Comment: I'm required to use that. All I want to know is how to convert x_train and y_train into a Dataloader, including the channel dimension.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to your `x_train` and `y_train`, but probably this works:

```
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

# use x_train and y_train as numpy array without further modification
x_train = np.array(trainset.data)
y_train = np.array(trainset.targets)

# convert to numpys to tensor
tensor_x = torch.Tensor(x_train) 
tensor_y = torch.Tensor(y_train)
# create the dataset
custom_dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_x,tensor_y) 
# create your dataloader
my_dataloader = DataLoader(custom_dataset,batch_size=1) 

#check if you can get the desired things
i1, l1 = next(iter(my_dataloader))
print(i1.shape)   # torch.Size([1, 1, 28, 28]) 
print(l1.shape)   # torch.Size([1])
```